# Angular: Como alterar o estilo do componente de paginação do ng-bootstrap [resolvida]

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando um componente de paginação do ng-bootstrap (link: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples).

Ele inicialmente é deste modo: [Paginação do ng-bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nclQ4.png).
Mas queria saber se é possível alterar ele e deixar nesse estilo: [Estilo alterado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIiOC.png).

Se for realmente possível, gostaria de saber como fazer isso, pois estou tentando pegar os elementos que compõem esse componente pelo Inspect do navegador e alterar pelo CSS, mas não está sendo aplicada nenhuma alteração que estou tentando fazer =(

**component.html**

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [boundaryLinks]="true" [pageSize]="pageSize" (pageChange)="refreshContent()">
  <ng-template ngbPaginationPages let-page let-pages="pages">
    <li class="ngb-custom-pages-item" *ngIf="pages.length > 0">
      <div class="mb-3 d-flex flex-nowrap px-2">
        <label id="paginationInputLabel" for="paginationInput" class="col-form-label me-2 ms-1">Page</label>
        <input
          #i
          type="text"
          inputmode="numeric"
          pattern="[0-9]*"
          class="form-control custom-pages-input"
          id="paginationInput"
          [value]="page"
          (keyup.enter)="selectPage(i.value)"
          (blur)="selectPage(i.value)"
          (input)="formatInput($any($event).target)"
          aria-labelledby="paginationInputLabel paginationDescription"
          style="width: 2.5rem"
        />
        <span id="paginationDescription" class="col-form-label text-nowrap px-2"> of {{pages.length}}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: Veja essa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357847/how-to-customize-the-css-for-ng-bootstrap-controls-using-angular-2-bootstrap-4, mas se não resolver tem várias outras perguntas com várias respostas no SO em inglês.

Comment: Ajudou sim, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver acessando os elementos pelo CSS, usando no `::ng-deep`. No fim ficou deste jeito:

**component.html**

```
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [boundaryLinks]="false" [pageSize]="pageSize" (pageChange)="refreshContent()">
      <ng-template ngbPaginationPages let-page let-pages="pages">
        <li class="ngb-custom-pages-item" *ngIf="pages.length > 0">
          <div class="mb-3 d-flex flex-nowrap px-2 div-pagination">
            <label id="paginationInputLabel" for="paginationInput" class="col-form-label me-2 ms-1">Page {{ page }} of {{ pages.length }}</label>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-pagination>
```

**component.css**

```
ngb-pagination {
 max-height: 50px;
}

ngb-pagination::ng-deep ul.pagination > li.page-item:first-child > a {
 border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

ngb-pagination::ng-deep ul.pagination > li.page-item:last-child > a {
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

ngb-pagination::ng-deep ul.pagination > li.page-item:first-child > a,
ngb-pagination::ng-deep ul.pagination > li.page-item:last-child > a {
 color: white;
 background-color: #007CC1;
 border-block-width: 0px;
 height: 38px;
}

div.div-pagination {
  padding-inline: 0 !important;

  label#paginationInputLabel {
   color: white;
   background-color: #007CC1;
   margin-inline: 0 !important;
   padding-inline: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).